# How to flatten a 2D array in julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a function in julia which converts a 2D array to a 1D array?
For example I know how to do it by defining a function, but I don't want to write it every time.

```
function flatten(Mat)
n, m = size(Mat)
flattened = zeros(m*n)
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        flattened[(i-1)*m + j] = Mat[i,j]
    end
end
return flattened
end
```

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.flatten ?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `vec` (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.vec):

```
julia> A = rand(2, 2)                                                     
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.843062  0.164179
 0.167501  0.800111

julia> vec(A)                                                             
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.8430624537022231 
 0.16750120450998196
 0.16417911360611237
 0.8001111380491013
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want rows to be stacked next to each other, and this needs transposing the array.

Comment: Julia is column major, so going row wise will necessarily be slower, I don't think it's a good idea. You should try to design your algorithms to work along columns, if possible. If you have to, you can use `vec(A')`.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the current solutions, `Iterators.flatten` does this in a lazy way, not moving things in memory but defining an iterator returning the elements one by one:

```
julia> A = rand(2,2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.667687  0.016606
 0.720289  0.12541 

julia> collect(Iterators.flatten(A))
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6676867119775669  
 0.7202889070377703  
 0.016606038041509397
 0.12540966422381583
```

Eagerly, you can use a for-comprehension over the indices of A:

```
julia> [A[i] for i in eachindex(A)]
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.6676867119775669  
 0.7202889070377703  
 0.016606038041509397
 0.12540966422381583
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you work in column-major form to take advantage of julia's array ordering:

```
A = randn(10,10)
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
```

```
a = A[:]
100-element Array{Float64,1}:
```

where `:` puts each column sequentially into the output vector.